# The Opposite of Frugal

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which might be used to describe the unnecessary and lavish expenditure of money.

I seem to recall this particular word roughly being the opposite of 'frugal'.

An example sentence might be; "The Decor of Sir Wilfred's house pointed to a _____ lifestyle"

Comment: [spendthrift/wasteful](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/frugal)

Comment: [lavish/profligate](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/frugal)

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'profligate' was the first to come to mind, but it wasn't in thesaurus.com's list. As great as that site is, I am often disappointed that what I think is the exact match is sometimes just not even on their list. I think that has more to say about the complexity of English vocab than the site.

Comment: @Mitch: Yeah - I had "profligate" in mind when I followed your link in the first place. So I couldn't help noticing that I actually had to *type* it (as opposed to my usual labour-saving cut&paste approach) - but I couldn't be bothered to find a different link to a page that really did list it, so I just repeated yours anyway! :)

Comment: As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange should demonstrate some initial research effort, such as checking a thesaurus for antonyms of *frugal*. I do encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on writing strong questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prodigal:

> adj  a. Extravagant; recklessly wasteful of one's property or means.
>
> *For what little of the mixed hardwood stands had survived..at the end of the seventeenth century had been laid waste by greedy and prodigal princelings.*
>
> OED

and

> Adjective: spending large amounts of money without thinking of the future, in a way that is not wise:
>
> *There have been rumours that he has been prodigal with company funds.*

Although the meaning is a clear antonym for 'frugal', there may be an argument that it's being most commonly used in association with 'son' in reference to the parable of the prodigal son, creates a certain potential for confusion over the meaning in some quarters with people thinking it is to with returning after an absence rather than being spendthrift.

Comment: Ah yes, you have triggered my memory. The example sentence was slightly misleading, but the word I was looking for was **Prodigality**

Comment: I do seem to have a knack of helping you light upon the words you have mislaid!

Comment: What would I do without you! Rest assured, there will be more to come

Answer (score 7):

I'd use **profligate**, as [per the Google response](https://www.google.com/search?q=profligate&oq=Profligate&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2102j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> recklessly extravagant or wasteful in the use of resources.

[image: From Googl]

Answer (score 2):

[Spendthrift](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spendthrift)

> a person who spends improvidently or wastefully

This is the first word that ever comes to my mind for the needs of this question. The word   is in general use.

Answer (score 1):

*Extravagant* works well in this context, I think. From the OED, 'Exceeding the bounds of economy or necessity in expenditure, mode of living, etc.; profuse, prodigal, wasteful.'

Answer (score 0):

***Opulent***, perhaps:

> *Rich, wealthy, affluent; ostentatiously luxurious or grand, sumptuous* (OED)

Answer (score 0):

I see only one adjective:
luxurious 
: characterized by opulence, sumptuousness, or rich abundance : of, relating to, or marked by luxury.
For example: luxurious accommodations
(From Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

Consider *squandering*, the present participle of the verb 'to squander':

> to spend extravagantly or foolishly

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squandering))

*extravagant* itself would work as well, I guess.