# Word to describe one capable of providing necessary things, but prioritize unnecessary things instead and expects help afterward

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Example:

Someone who purchases clothes, furnishings, trips, home renovations etc. but then pleads with friends or starts gofundme for assistance with pet surgery, car repairs, etc.

Comment: Pleading poverty?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You have correctly used the [single-word-requests] tag, but please take a moment to read [the tag help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). In particular, we need a sample sentence because we need to know whether you want a noun or an adjective -- or indeed something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Opposite of Frugal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476604/the-opposite-of-frugal)

Comment: Obviously not a duplicate as 'non-frugal' does not have the 'and expects help afterwards' requirement. But doubtless all the answers would be duplicates.